# Generate php code to pdf

Tags: php, dompdf

I'm using dompdf to generate PDF from a php file. This is the full code of the file:

```
<?php 

// INCLUDEM CONFIGUL SI INITIALIZAM CLASELE DE SISTEM
require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'initialize.php';
require_once("/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

// Database
// Conectarea LA BAZA DE DATE !!!
$db = new MySQLDatabase();

// Session
// SESIUNEA CARE TINE UTILIZATORUL LOGAT !
$session=new Session();      
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link href="main.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allura' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo HTTP_FRONT; ?>js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <title>Sanovita</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.AdaugaCategoriile p#1').hide();
        $('.AdaugaCategoriile p#2').hide();
        $('.AdaugaCategoriile p#3').hide();
        $('.AdaugaCategoriile p#4').hide();

        $('#categorie').change(function(){

            var categorie = $(this).val();

            $('.AdaugaCategoriile p#1').hide();
            $('.AdaugaCategoriile p#2').hide();
            $('.AdaugaCategoriile p#3').hide();
            $('.AdaugaCategoriile p#4').hide();

            $('.AdaugaCategoriile p#'+categorie).show();
        });

    });
    </script>
    <div id="Body">
        <div id="Header">
            <div id="HeaderLogo">
                <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="Menu">
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Content">
            <div class="Categorii">  
                <?php 

                // daca nu exista id-ul produsului
                if(isset($_GET['id']))
                {
                    $res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `vanzari` WHERE `id_client`=".$_GET['id']." AND `finalizat`=0");   

                    $categoriile = '<table>
                            <th width="2%">Nr.</th>
                            <th width="15%">Nume Client</th>
                            <th width="15%">Nume Angajat</th>
                            <th width="15%">Produs</th>
                            <th>Data</th>
                            <th>Cantitate</th>
                            <th width="10%">Total pret</th>
                            <th width="15%">Stare</th>
                            <th>Actiuni</th>';

                    $x = 1;
                    // AFISEZ PRODUSELE
                    for($i=0; $i<$res->num_rows; $i++)
                    {
                        $client = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `clienti` WHERE `id`=".$res->rows[$i]['id_client']."");
                        $produs_vanzare = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `produse` WHERE `id`=".$res->rows[$i]['id_produs']."");
                        $angajat = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `utilizatori` WHERE `id`=".$res->rows[$i]['id_angajat']."");

                        if($res->rows[$i]['finalizat'] == 0)
                        {
                            $status = 'In curs de finalizare';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $status = 'Finalizat';
                        }

                        // daca produsul e par
                        if(($i%2)==0)
                        {
                            $categoriile .= "
                            <tr class='odd'>
                                <td><p>".$x."</p></td>
                                <td><p>".$client->row['nume_client']."</p></td>
                                <td><p>".$angajat->row['firstname']. ' ' . $angajat->row['lastname']."</p></td>
                                <td><p>".$produs_vanzare->row['name']."</p></td>
                                <td><p>".$res->rows[$i]['data']."</p></td>
                                <td><p>".$res->rows[$i]['bucati']."</p></td>
                                <td><p>".$res->rows[$i]['total_pret']." RON</p></td>
                                <td><p>".$status."</p></td>
                                <td><a href='".HTTP_FRONT."vanzari.php?id_vanzare=".$res->rows[$i]['id']."&id=".$client->row['id']."'><p>Sterge</p></a></td>     
                            </tr>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $categoriile .= "
                            <tr class='even'>
                                <td><p>".$x."</p></td>
                                <td><p>".$client->row['nume']."</p></td>
                                <td><p>".$angajat->row['firstname']. ' ' . $angajat->row['lastname']."</p></td>
                                <td><p>".$produs_vanzare->row['name']."</p></td>
                                <td><p>".$res->rows[$i]['data']."</p></td>
                                <td><p>".$res->rows[$i]['bucati']."</p></td>
                                <td><p>".$res->rows[$i]['total_pret']." RON</p></td>
                                <td><p>".$status."</p></td>
                                <td><a href='".HTTP_FRONT."vanzari.php?id_vanzare=".$res->rows[$i]['id']."&id=".$client->row['id']."'><p>Sterge</p></a></td>  
                            </tr>";
                        }

                        $x++;
                    }                        
                    $categoriile .= "</table><div class='clear'></div>";

                    if(!isset($session->data['finalizat']))
                    {
                        echo $categoriile;
                    }
                }

                ?>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="Footer">
            <p>Copyright &copy; 2013</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<?php
$html = ob_get_clean();
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("factura.pdf");

?>
```

The dompdf is generating me only the HTML part, but the php one doesn't show. In config, the DOM_ENABLE_PHP is set to true.
What can be the problem ?

Comment: If you want to make it easier on us, make a small-as-possible example that has the problem. Probably if you did `<html><body><p>test</p></body></html>` instead of all your code, you'd still have the problem, and it would be much easier to find the issues. If you do that and it _doesn't_ show the issue, you are all of a sudden a lot closer to a solution!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to catch all your output (at least, that's what I think to find from your `ob_get_clean();` use. But you never call `ob_start`, so you're probably just pushing all the data to the browser/output, and get nothing there.

Just build your html in a string, then use that for input.

try this

```
<?php 
require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'initialize.php';
require_once("/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

$db = new MySQLDatabase();
$session=new Session();      

$html =  <<<HTML
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p>
test
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
HTML;

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("factura.pdf");

?>
```

Comment: I've put the ob_start(); at the beginning, but it doesn't appear any of php data. How to use the html in a string ? I don't understand it...

Comment: I don't see your `ob_start()`? Anyway, check out my comment: make a _REALLY SMALL_ example, remove all the database stuff for instance. Read http://sscce.org/ if you need it :) ..

Comment: (and how can you put `ob_start()` in your source, but not have it show? It is either in your source or it isn't. Anyway, see my edit. That html should've been in your question (I mean that! that would help us a great deal).

Comment: I've tested the code you gave me, it works. I've also made a test with a php script like echo 'Test';, and it works too. May it not be compatible with MySQL connection ?!

Comment: well, as you can see, my code doesn't do anything with `ob_get_clean`, so use that method: put the html in a string (I'm using `HEREDOC`, look it up) and use that. (I'm still confused how you say you have `ob_start`, but do not show it in your code)

Comment: about the ob_start, i've put it after you told me first time, that's why i said i've got it :)

Comment: Ah, check ;)  Next time you might want to update your question, so new passer-by's can check the complete problem :). Anyway, it looks like you're fine if you just step away from the `ob_` functions, and build a string with your html like I did.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing all your PHP-generated output into `$categoriile`. Then you're checking if IS NOT set `$session->data['finalizat']`... Perhaps you're not meeting this condition. Check `$session->data['finalizat']`. You also do not have ob_start (per Nanne's notice)

Comment: I've put the ob_start, but it doesn't show it. About the storing, I tested the code on a php page, and the php is giving me all the info, so the php code is working.